# Copy output of sql-query to a file

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell

I want to export a random entry of my database into a file with the command

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1 \g /path/file;
```

This query works if I enter it in my db terminal, but I want to us this query with a bash script but then I get the error: syntax error at or near "\g"

My bash script looks like this:

```
 PGPASSWORD=*** psql -U user -d db_name -h localhost -p port -t -c "SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1 \g /path/file"
```

Comment: try the command `COPY (SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1) TO '/Users/testuser/Downloads/testfile.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;`

Answer (score 0):

Bash is interpreting the string and trying to interpolate it. Probably, escaping the backslash will solve your problem.

```
PGPASSWORD=*** psql -U user -d db_name -h localhost -p port -t -c "SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1 \\g /path/file"
```

Answer (score 0):

A SQL statement terminated by `\g` is not supported by the `-c` command switch. Per [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) of `-c`:

> -c command
>   ...
>   command must be either a command string that is completely parsable by the server (i.e., it  contains no psql-specific features), or a single backslash command. Thus you cannot mix SQL
>    and psql meta-commands with this option

To redirect the results to a file, there are several options:

- shell redirection: `psql [other options] -Atc 'SELECT...' >/path/to/data.txt`
  `-A` is to switch to unaligned mode (no space fillers to align columns).
- put the SQL part in a [heredoc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)  text instead of the command line:

  ```
  psql [options] <<EOF
   SELECT ... \g /path/to/file
   EOF
  ```

  This  form has the advantage that multiline statements or multiple statements are supported directly.
- `\copy` of the query. Be aware that COPY to a FILE is different: it creates the file on the server with the permissions of `postgres` and requires being a database superuser. `COPY TO STDOUT` works too but is not better than SELECT concerning the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my script, and now it works.

```
#!/bin/bash


RANDOM_NUMBER=0
while true
do
        for i in `seq 1`
        do
                RANDOM_NUMBER=$(($RANDOM % 100000))
                echo $RANDOM_NUMBER
                PGPASSWORD=*** psql -U user_name -d db_name -h localhost -p PORT -c 
"INSERT INTO numbers (number) VALUES ('$RANDOM_NUMBER');"
        done
        sleep 10
        for i in `seq 1`
        do
                PGPASSWORD=*** psql -U user_name -d db_name -h localhost -p PORT -c 
"DELETE FROM numbers WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM numbers ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1);"

        done

done
```